# Remove shadow from Android ImageButton

Tags: android, button, shadow

How can I remove the shadow from an ImageButton in Android?

What is the underlying resource that contains the shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadow wasn't on the ImageButton at all, it was added to the image itself when I created an icon set in Eclipse. By re-creating that icon set with no shape, the shadow was eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a transparent color to android:shadowColor property of your ImageButton.

Comment: Have you tried zeroing other shadow properties? like shadowDx, shadowDy, shadowRadius?